# displaying a jsp page after another jsp page

Tags: ajax, jsp

I am doing a jsp project; here I am using two text fields in first.jsp and retrieving those values in second.jsp. I want to display the text field values in the same page in browser after submit button.  I don’t know ajax…,

first.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="second.jsp">
        First Name:  <input type="text" name="fname">
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">

    </form>
</body>
```

second.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <%
        String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
        String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
    %>
    First Name is <%=fname%><br><br>
    Last Name is <%=lname%>
</body>
```

Please help me …..,

Comment: DO u want to send it to the database?coz if not then jquery should do the trick..

Comment: No need for sending to database..,Give the solution using jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a session bean to store the value submitted from second.jsp so that first.jsp can access it. - however, using session bean is not a very good practice.

Comment: solution using ajax.?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a form then if you not using database

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button:#submit").click(function () {

$("#submit").click(function () {

$('#finame').html($('#fname').val());
$('#laname').html($('#lname').val());

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
                    First Name:  <input type="text" id="fname">
        Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname"><br><br>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>

 <div>
    First Name : <label id="finame"></label><br />
    Last Name : <label id="laname"></label>
</div>
</body>
```

This is the jsfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/sNpeL/4/